# CakePHP Router::connect regarding to query parameters

Tags: cakephp, redirect, url-routing, cakephp-2.0

In my controller's beforeFilter I check this type of request and redirect:

```
if ( array_key_exists('myparameter',$this->request->query) ) {
    $this->redirect("http://example.com/".$this->request->url,301);
}
```

But it seems like making this redirection from **routes.php** is more cake-ish.
So how can I put this logic inside a [Router::connect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) ?

Comment: Have you checked the Redirect Routing section in the Cook Book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not adequate for query parameters.